# How to read a bytes file written in Java with Python

Tags: java, arrays, file, byte

I have two separate large array of type short and int in Java (Android). I want to write them in a file and later read them in Python to recreate the array. The problem is, I think the file is created and written correctly in Java, but I am unable to read the file correctly in Python.
I am using following bits of code in Java to write the array.

```
File mFile = new File( this.getExternalFilesDir(null),"testFile.txt");
ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(mFile));
objectOutputStream.writeObject(intArray);
objectOutputStream.close();
```

I also wrote the file using the following method looping over the array (which I think also works just fine)

```
File mFile = new File( this.getExternalFilesDir(null),"testFile.txt");
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
for (int x: intArray) {
    outputStream.write(x);
}
objectOutputStream.close();
```

How do I read this file and create the array in python. I tried referring the Python struct library but was unable to use it.
I tries the following code to read in Python.
I tried a demo array
[1000, 1001, 1002, 1003,.....,1025]

```
with open('/../testFile.txt') as mFile:
    for ln in mFile:
        print( list( struct.unpack('I*'(len(ln)//4), ln) ) )
```

This raise Error "error: unpack requires a buffer of 104 bytes" at the print statement.

Comment: "*I am unable to read the file correctly in Python*" Where is the python code you've written? What happens when you run it?

Comment: AnObjectOutputStream is java specific storing classes and objects (their attributes and so on. Use a DataOutputStream, and read the ints as big endian (or use a ByteBuffer)

Comment: You can't read this data at all in Python. Only in Java.

Comment: The big problem is that you ask about a file of bytes, but you're not even making a file of int's. The best way I can think of it to write the file in bytes, with network byte order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Joop Eggen's comment I modified the Java code to write data using DataOutputStream and read the file using Big Endian format (something I was not doing and Joop Eggen's pointed out). Here is the Java code.

```
short[] mBuffer = {1000, 1001,....,1025};
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(mBuffer.length*2);
ShortBuffer sBuffer = byteBuffer.asShortBuffer();
sBuffer.put(mBuffer);

File mFile = new File( this.getExternalFilesDir(null),"testFile.txt");
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
outputStream.write(byteBuffer.array());
```

The Python code to read and create the array.

```
with open('\..\testFile.txt', 'rb') as mFile:
    for ln in mFile:
        # To Read Short Array 
        print( list( struct.unpack('>' + 'h'*(len(ln)//2), ln) ) )
        # To Read Int Array
        print( list( struct.unpack('>' + 'i'*(len(ln)//4), ln) ) )

Output : [1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008, 1009, 1010, 1011, 1012, 1013, 1014, 1015, 1016, 1017, 1018, 1019, 1020, 1021, 1022, 1023, 1024]
```